# "grep" command on Solaris system is needed for using on Unix

Tags: unix, search, grep, command, solaris

"grep" command in solaris is for searching specific names in a directory . I need this command in Unix and Linux system . Would you help me ?

Comment: What problem are you having?   It's hard to help when you don't explain what went wrong when you tried using a standard command on those systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is a very standard command you'll already find installed in all Solaris and Gnu/Linux systems.